# protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)

Tags: java, swing, graphics

We can override the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of `JComponent`.

It is called automatically to refresh the screen.

What can I do that is called regularly, for example every 100 ms.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't seem to get the point of your question. Do you want to refresh the screen/window periodically every millisecond? Looks like you're trying to deal with animation, am I right?

Comment: Copyedited; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: Related examples may be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114490) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256941).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your purpose is refreshing the component every certain ms?

If so, there's a few options available.
The use of `Timer`  is a first option. Example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Timerbasedanimation.htm). 
The option most people use is `Thread` animation. Here is an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Threads/AnimationSwingandthread.htm). 

Also there's a timing framework available to download. I can't find an available link, but just search for it on the internet.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can request that the component repaint itself with a call to [repaint](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29)().  You most certainly do not want to call repaint every 1 ms though; no monitor in the world could display at 1000 Hz, and no human eye would distinguish that either.  Furthermore the repaint calls would be coalesced into a few separate ones and you would not achieve that number of repaints.

What are you trying to achieve?  I assume it's some sort of animation; if so you should start googling for "java 2d swing animation" or some variant of that.  Try this [2d java tutorial](http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part1/Supplements/Chapter08/dropAnimation.html) for starters.